# How to find the distance between two location on map i

Tags: android, android-location, google-developers-console

How to find the distance between two locations on android ecillipse project &php .the project is based on online  good transport system .The fare of the carrier needed to be found out so  there is a need of finding distance between source & destination .Harversine formula was implemented for finding the shortest vehicle in the region

Comment: Location.distanceBetween(
    startLatitude,
    startLongitude,
    endLatitude,
    endLongitude,
    results);

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(source.latitude, source.longitude,
                    destination.latitude, destination.longitude,
                    results);
```

> Computes the approximate distance in meters between two
>        locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the
>        shortest path between them.  Distance and bearing are defined using the
>        WGS84 ellipsoid. The computed distance is stored in results[0].  If results has length
>         2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has
>         length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].
>
> ```
>   @param startLatitude the starting latitude
>   @param startLongitude the starting longitude
>   @param endLatitude the ending latitude
>   @param endLongitude the ending longitude
>   @param results an array of floats to hold the results
>
>   @throws IllegalArgumentException if results is null or has length < 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
double _distance = Location.distanceBetween(
                 _firstLatitude,
                 _firstLongitude,
                 _secondLatitude,
                 _secondLongitude,
                 _results);
```